# Rx.Observable.repeat (indefinitely) with zip causes the browser to stop responding

Tags: rxjs

**The following code causes the browser to stop responding, using a value like '100' for example for the repeat solves the problem, but in my case I don't have specific value for it.
Would you please suggest a solution:**

```
var observer = Rx.Observer.create(function (x)
                                  {
                                     console.log(x);
                                  },
                                  function (err)
                                  {
                                     console.log('Error: ' + err);
                                  },
                                  function ()
                                  {
                                     console.log('Completed');
                                  });

var repeat = Rx.Observable.repeat(10, null); //repeat indefinitely
var interval = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);

var zip = Rx.Observable.zip(repeat,
                            interval,
                            function(rep, inter)
                            {
                               return rep + inter;
                            });

zip.subscribe(observer);
```

Answer (score 1):

The browser freezes because `.repeat` simply yields `10` indefinitely.

Since Rx is push-based, we have no way of knowing when `zip` needs another item. Instead, we just push new values to `zip` as they become available. The static (class-method?) `repeat` says "hey, I have new items RIGHT NOW ALWAYS HERE THEY ARE" and never relinquishes control-flow back to zip. This means zip never actually ends up subscribing to the `interval` observable, so zip just starts buffering indefinitely.

If you're coming from a functional background, then it would seem like an "infinite" list of "10"s would zip nicely with a finite list of anything. Which is absolutely true, assuming your infinite list is lazy. In this case, our "list" has a mind of it's own, and definitely isn't lazy.

I'd be happy to suggest a solution, but it seems that the example is contrived. What exactly are you attempting to do?

Comment: I've posted a related question which might be helpful to readers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893983/create-infinite-repeatable-observable-from-array. Would you mind having a look?

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same problem. Looks like `delay` can do the trick.

Here's the slightly modified version of your code:

```
var observer = Rx.Observer.create(function (x)
                                  {
                                     console.log(x);
                                  },
                                  function (err)
                                  {
                                     console.log('Error: ' + err);
                                  },
                                  function ()
                                  {
                                     console.log('Completed');
                                  });

var repeat = Rx.Observable.of(10).delay(0).repeat(-1); //repeat indefinitely
var interval = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);

var zip = Rx.Observable.zip(repeat,
                            interval,
                            function(rep, inter)
                            {
                               return rep + inter;
                            });

zip.subscribe(observer);
```